# Alignment issue in ui-grid where data & columns tends to change

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular-ui-grid

I use UI-grid(ui-grid - v3.0.7) for displaying data.

```
    var gridOptions = {};
    gridOptions.paginationPageSizes= [10,25,50];
    gridOptions.paginationPageSize= 10;
    gridOptions.enableSorting = true;
    gridOptions.enableColumnMenus=false;
    gridOptions.data = "data";
    gridOptions.enableColumnResizing = false;
    gridOptions.enableCellEdit = false;
    gridOptions.enableGridMenu = false;
    gridOptions.rowHeight=25;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    $scope.sampleFunction = function() {
        $scope.data = //servicecall;
        // here the service call tend to render json that may have different columns
    }
```

The problem is that, as the data and columnDefs change dynamically, the grid is expected to be rendered as follows
[Dynamically the rows should fix itself to the maximum width for the given data(eg: incase of 12 columns the column header and data should fix itself within the grid's 100% width)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UASvt.png) Whereas, Incase of columns the column header and data should stretch itself & fix itself within the grid's 100% width

But actually how these grid objects are rendered is as follows:
[the width of the header and grid records are reduced depending on it's respective cell-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynfZ0.png)

I surfed through few solutions and added the below fix immediately after the data is appended to the grid.

```
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

But that didn't work as well.